# PHP PDO SQLite. Transaction and updating problems

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, transactions, sql-update

I have a problem with a transaction in PHP-PDO-SQLite and updating.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database1.sqlite');

/*
$rowsnumber1 = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
question TEXT NOT NULL,
answers INTEGER NOT NULL
)");
print('$rowsnumber1: '.$rowsnumber1.'<br />');

$rowsnumber2 = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
qid INTEGER NOT NULL,
answer TEXT NOT NULL
)");
print('$rowsnumber2: '.$rowsnumber2.'<br />');
*/

//print('Inserting: '); $res = $db->exec("INSERT INTO questions (question,answers) VALUES ('Question',0)"); var_dump($res); print('<br />');

$qid = 1;

try
{
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->beginTransaction();

// Variant 1
//print('Executing 1: '); $res1 = $db->exec("INSERT INTO answers (qid,answer) VALUES ($qid,'Answer')"); var_dump($res1); print('<br />');
//print('Executing 2: '); $res2 = $db->exec("UPDATE questions SET answers = answers+1 WHERE id = '".$qid."'"); var_dump($res2); print('<br />');

// Variant 2
print('Preparing 1: '); $statement1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (qid,answer) VALUES (:qid,:answer)"); var_dump($statement1); print('<br />');
print('Preparing 2: '); $statement2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE questions SET answers = answers+1 WHERE id='".$qid."'"); var_dump($statement2); print('<br />');

print('Executing 1: '); $res1 = $statement1->execute(array('qid'=>$qid,'answer'=>'Answer')); var_dump($res1); print('<br />');
print('Executing 2: '); $res2 = $statement2->execute(); var_dump($res2); print('<br />');

$db->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$db->rollBack();
print("Transaction failed: " .$e->getMessage());
}
```

There is no problem when "id" of the question and "qid" of the answer is the same ($qid). The problem begins when I try to insert an answer with "id" of the question, which doesn't exist in the table "questions". For example, in the table "questions" there is one question ("id" is "1") and you try to insert an answer to the question with "id" = "5". The answer is inserted, but the question is not updated (the cell "answers" is not incremented) because there is no question with such an "id" = "5". The matter is that transaction doesn't make a rollback and updating is executed with the result "true", though actually there is no updating.
What is wrong with the transaction and why updating returns "true" when I use a statement ?

Answer (score 1):

I have understood what I did wrong.
The matter is that there is no logic in 'try' section.
Before $db->commit(); I should have written next two lines:

```
if($res1 != 1) throw new Exception("Inserting the answer failed");
if($res2 != 1) throw new Exception("Updating the question failed");
```

About prepare(); and execute(); - I have read inattentively the manual of PDO here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
The matter is that execute(); returns 'true' in case the statement is executed, but doesn't check whether or not it affected a row.
And the method exec(); checks if the row was affected. I.e. methods prepare(); and execute(); are not suitable in this situation.
I should have used 'Variant 1', which I commented.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, only after allowing the write access problem persisted.

Apparantly I had "foreign key constraint failed" error inside the transaction which was failing the commit.

I had to get my database tables straight and problem was solved.

I hope this helps someone.